# Shell script to call another script for password

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script which has password in clear text used in a command :

```
--username = 'USER'
--password ='abc100'
```

I dont want the password to be in clear text here in shell script. Is there a way i can keep this shell script password protected or to not pass the password in clear text and refer another file which is password protected ?

Comment: Sounds like a stupid command wanting password as an argument. What command are you referring to?

Comment: Are you allowed to prompt user for a password? If so you can use `read -s` to store it in command & variable

Comment: @andlrc - I have a cloud invocation command which will need me to pass the password of the cloud instance i want to login into.

Comment: @Inian- No prompt allowed. Password will be fixed and should be picked in the shell scrip

Comment: @sreekembose: the requirement is not quite clear. You have the username/password in a script which you want to be hidden from plain view? (or) pass it to another script?

Comment: want to be hidden from plain view @Inian

Comment: Why not also pass username and password via arguments? All the way up to the root?

Comment: What's the name of the command?

Comment: One scheme employed by `cifs.mount`, etc.. is to source a file at a known location in the users home directory that is set read-only for that user. (e.g. `[ -r "$HOME/.config/credentials" ] && . "$HOME/.config/credentials"` where the permissions are set `chmod 0600` on the `credentials` file) You can also pass the filename as an argument to your script. (of course, the script must run as the normal user for this scheme to work)

Answer (score 1):

To solve this question well, it's really important to know how what this password represents and what sort of risks compromising it entails. It's also important to understand who has access to the machine on which this script and password file are stored, how the machines are set up, who needs to run this script, etc. It's really hard to give a good answer without understanding the full requirements and risks.

Assuming that compromising this password could have seriously negative repercussions and assuming that lots of people who should not have this password need to run this script, it would -- in my view -- be a mistake to store this password on the machines of everyone who needs to run this. You may want to consider having a smaller number of machines with much more limited access store this password and offer the functionality of the script through a webservice that uses an authentication mechanism such as [OAuth](https://oauth.net/2/) (with [Bearer tokens](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) for automated access). Then the question becomes how do individual users have a script access the Bearer tokens needed to invoke the web service; although the Bearer tokens are also sensitive, they would at least be unique per user (giving a way to better detect compromise and abuse, though that is something you would still need to implement). In that sense, the question becomes similar to the original question, but with lower stakes.

Assuming that we are now talking about storing Bearer tokens, how you store it will depend on how many different users can access the same machine / filer system. For example, if many different people can have root access on the same machine, there is very little you can do. If there is one user per machine, however, and only that machine's owner can gain root, then you can use UNIX permissions to help limit / control access to files. For example, you could create a user+group that is dedicated to this specific script, have the script always run with that permission (e.g. via the sticky bit), and have the Bearer token information stored in a way that is readable only to that user/group (as a way to prevent other programs run by the same user from accessing that credential). In a setup where many people use the same machine but the people who can run as root can be trusted, you might just store the credential in a folder in the user's home directory that is accessible to only that user (and not readable/writable by the same group or other users); however, this does risk other programs run by that user reading the data. You could attempt to have the script encrypt/decrypt the content of the file on disk (e.g. embedding the key to encrypt/decrypt the data within the script), though unless the script were highly obfuscated and was regularly updated with this key rotated, that would do very little. You could also impose a short expiration on the bearer token so that the token need to be refreshed often as a mitigation measure to other programs misusing the token after it is no longer being used.